# Status of Obsolete and Exited in Jbpm

Tags: task, status, jbpm, obsolete

I have tried to abort the task in different JBPM version. In Jbpm 5.2.0.Final version, aborted task status changed as 'Obsolete', but in Jbpm 5.4.0.Final version aborted task status changed as 'Exited'.

Could you please explain why this difference occurs also what is the difference between Obsolete & Exited status in jbpm.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the latest [offical documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.42.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_jbpmtasklifecycle) as well as the related [Human-Task Standard](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/specs/ws-bpel4people/WS-HumanTask_v1.pdf)

- The task status `Obsolete` is set if the user *skipping a task* (possible if the task has been marked as skippable), in which case the task will not be executed. This gets handled as a 'positive outcome'.
- The task status `Exited` is set if the parent *application needs to end* prematurely before the invoked human task has been completed. This is a 'negative outcome'.